# Doxygen globally defined reference links

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

In Doxygen you use reference links: define them separately and then refer to them from within the text.

```
/**
 * This is a documentation. Here I link [std::string] to an external web page.
 *
 * The next line is the link definition:
 *
 * [std::string]: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string "std::string documentation"
*/
```

However it seems that the link definition is seen only within the documentation block. It is not seen even on other documentation blocks on the same page.

I want to define some links once, and then use them everywhere (on different pages).

Is that possible?

---

**Edit** (follow-up question)

> In order to achieve your aim I think your best bet is to make use of the ALIAS facility.

I have managed to set it up with alias like this:

```
ALIASES += std_string="<a href=\"http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string\" title=\"std::string documentation\" target=\"_blank\">std::string</a> "
ALIASES += std_vector="<a href=\"http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector\" title=\"std::vector documentation\" target=\"_blank\">std::vector</a> "
```

And using it:

```
@std_string
@std_vector
```

Basically I have one alias for each link.

Can it be achieved with one alias with parameters? The use would be:

```
@std_ref std::string
@std_ref std::vector
```

The problem is that some sort of map is needed between the name (the parameter) and the link:

```
std::string -> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string 
std::vector -> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
```

I know it can be done if one parameter would be the different part of the link, like :

```
@std_ref std::string string/basic_string 
@std_ref std::vector container/vector
```

But this is ugly, error prone and would require to check each time what the link should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that what you are currently using is the notation that comes only with Doxygen's support for **Markdown** - it's not the doxygen method for external links. The original Doxygen method is to insert an HTML link inline...

`<a href="linkURL">link text</a>`

... but that makes no difference to your original problem.

In order to achieve your aim I think your best bet is to make use of the ALIAS facility.  The relevant manual page is [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html).  Using them, you should be able to define an alias like `std-string` and have it insert the HTML link *everywhere* you use the alias.

ALIASES are set up in the doxyfile config file (in [this section](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#config_project) of the manual)

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I have a question regarding using only one alias with parameters instead of one alias for each link. I would appreciate if you would check my question edit.

Comment: I've never had need to use the mixture of alias and parameters, so you're getting outside of my experience.  Sorry, we've got to the stage where your guess is as good as mine :)

Comment: That's ok, your answer solved my problem, I just wanted to go a step further.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* set up aliases manually for every C++ keyword, that you want to link to, but the better way to do this is to use the doxygen TAGFILES feature.

> A tag file is basically a compact representation of the entities found in the external sources. Doxygen can both generate and read tag files.
>
> To generate a tag file for your project, simply put the name of the tag file after the GENERATE_TAGFILE option in the configuration file.
>
> To combine the output of one or more external projects with your own project you should specify the name of the tag files after the TAGFILES option in the configuration file.

Doxygen has a whole page dedicated to explaining [how to link to external documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html)

And cppreference.com has already setup a tag file for you with some [basic instructions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives).

For the impatient:

1. Download [File:cppreference-doxygen-web.tag.xml](http://en.cppreference.com/w/File:cppreference-doxygen-web.tag.xml) for linking directly to cppreference.com website.
2. Add this line to your Doxyfile:

   TAGFILES += "location/of/cppreference-doxygen-web.tag.xml=http://en.cppreference.com/w/"

Comment: could you clarify point 3. How to actually make use of these tags in the source code? If I do e.g. "@see std::distance" it doesn't work.